# How to make an avaudioplayer to stop playing previous song while clicking on newsong?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

I created a view with a button songs.

- When we click on button it goes to a table which contains list of
  songs.
- When we select a song it goes to another view and plays the song.
- Whenever the song is playing we can go back to main view or to the
  table of songs the song will be playing in background its fine upto
  here.

But whenever I try to play another song from the table of songs the previous song is not stopped and it continues to play along with the selected song.

My aim is play the song when it is switched to a different view. I have done this one but what I want is whenever I select another song from the table of songs it must stop the previous song and play the selected song.

Please solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the `avaudioplayer` and recreate the instance after releasing the existing one.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked 
{
 if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
 {
  [audioPlayer stop];
  [audioPlayer release];
  audioPlayer = nil;
  audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfUrl:songUrl];
  [audioPlayer play];
}
// Do something like change view etc.
}
```

If u are selecting from a table view put this in the `UITableView delegate` `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

Comment: in .h there is avaudioplayer *audioplayer

Comment: in .h i have written avaudioplayer *audioplayer ... in .m i have written the above code but its not working how can i get that old instance so that i can stop audioplayer to stop

Comment: u should use the same instance variable of avaudioplayer that u created in .h file

Comment: actually when its loading that page it is taking the instance variable in .h file .what actually happening whenever it is loading the page it is creating new instance variable for audioplayer so if we give [audioplayer stop]or any other it is for new instance variable its not overriding the old instance variable thats the problem i think what u say

Comment: U create an audioplayer instance when u select a song right? Then another view is shown. When we get back the audio is still running so when u select another song u should stop the audio that is being played by the instance variable. then create a new one with the new song

Comment: i have one more question actually now what is happenning is if iam selecting another song the previous song is stopped and selected song is playing.But if i select the same selected song once again it is also stopping how to make it continue??please tell

Comment: If the same song is selected do not stop the player. u can check this by checking the url. Stop the player only if a different song is selected.

Comment: from audioplayer instance how i can get the song that that is playing currently

Comment: musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
              pathForResource:h
              ofType:q]];
    
       
    a = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];

Comment: here "a" is instance of avaudioplayer how can i get the pathForResource from "a" or how can i get the details of song that is currently playing avaudioplayer

Comment: u can store the current url in a variable and then check when song is selected.

Comment: U select songs from table view right? then u can check the index itself

Comment: if i select the first song then i check index is 0 if i select second song index is 1 but i dont know which song is being played in avaudioplayer there lies the problem

Comment: U can store this index as current song index and then use it for the check

Comment: U can also use the audioPlayer.url property to get the current url. This is much easier.